# CSS - Медиа запросы. Некоректная последовательность активации медиазапросов

Tags: html, css, css3

Некорректная последовательность активации медиазапросов.
Предположим, что я имею блок div с классом container и следующий css файлик:

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
       .container {
           width: 200px
       }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
       .container {
           width: 500px
       }
  }
```

Почему сайт отображает стили в min-width: 700px, хотя ширина экрана меньше ?

Comment: А если просто  @media (min-width: 700px) написать?

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы на планшетах версия немного отличалась

Comment: Если посмотреть отладочную панель, то запросы работают корректно. Когда ширина области станет меньше 700px, то применяется стиль min-width: 320px. Возможно у вас кеш остался. Прописывали `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: Нет, не прописывал, а что это вообще ? XDD И куда это надо вписывать ?

Comment: А, всё, разобрался. Просто шарики за ролики заехали

Comment: Приложу сайт на котором находится  эта ошибка. Нужный элемент находится по адресу: body -> saitpage -> cartinALL    |   musicanime.ru

Comment: Возможно нашел проблему. К сожалению у меня нет планшета под рукой чтобы проверить, но браузер на пк определяет устройство как мобильное вплоть до 980px, поэтому, если указать в медиа запросе min-width: 981, то всё будет работать как надо (опять таки в случае пк версии, на мобильных устройствах может быть по другому. Дополню ответ, как только появится возможность воспользоваться планшетом.

Comment: такого не может быть или надо проверить zoom планшета или компьютера